# Window is not defined when importing library in build Jest-Lite

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic, import, jestjs

I have a file called test.jsx where I'm importing the dependency jest-lite. Jest-lite appear to need window to be able to run.

Here is my import:

```
import { describe, it, expect, run } from 'jest-lite';
```

In my view, at the click of a button, i call a certain function to be able to run my tests:

```
onClick={async (e) => {
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const test = (await import('../pages/test.jsx').then((r) => {
                const result = r.runTests().then(
                  x=> {
                    updateModalMessageRes(x[0]);
                    updateModalMessageTest(x[1]);
                  }
                  ,err=>console.warn("got rejected:",err)
                );
              })
            )
            }
            setShowModal(true);
        }}
```

**In dev mode**, everything works and appear great but when I need to build and go in prod, **window is not defined** appear.

I've tried to use dynamic import from NextJs but I don't know how to import selective module like {describe, it, expect, run}.

If some of you can explain to me how to use it or have a better solution it would be awesome !

**Edit 01/03/2023:**
I've tried to import dynamically this way:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const describe = dynamic(
  () => import("jest-lite").then((mod) => mod.describe),
  { ssr: false }
)
const it = dynamic(
  () => import("jest-lite").then((mod) => mod.it),
  { ssr: false }
)
const expect = dynamic(
  () => import("jest-lite").then((mod) => {mod.expect}),
  { ssr: false }
)
const run = dynamic(
  () => import("jest-lite").then((mod) => mod.run),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

But now there is a new error saying 'Can't resolve 'jest-lite'

Comment: try to put 'use client'; at the top of your file. but anyway tests shouldn't be in code. you should create a separate file. ps: window is not defined because nextjs compiles your stuff to static assets and window does not exist there. it only exists once you loaded the page in a browser

Comment: I know but I definitely need my tests to be available and be executable from the client side, hence jest-lite that permit this.